# Angular - How to resolve "Property does not exist on type 'never'" in @tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable Advanced Search

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In my Angular-13 project I am trying to implement Advance Search in [@tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcell-template%2Fcell-template.component.ts)

I have this code:

interface:

```
export interface Merchant {
  id?: number;
  merchant_name?: string;
  account_number?: string;
  merchant_status?: number;
  created_date?: string;
}
```

service:

```
  import { Merchant} from 'src/app/models/merchants.model';

  getAllMerchants(): Observable<Merchant[]> {
    return this.http.get<Merchant[]>(this.baseUrl + 'merchants');
  }
```

component.ts:

```
import { MerchantService } from 'src/app/services/merchant.service';
import { Merchant} from 'src/app/models/merchants.model';

export class MerchantsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('idTpl', { static: true }) idTpl!: TemplateRef<any>;
  allMerchantList: any[] = [];
  data = [];
  dataBK = this.allMerchantList;
  options = {};
  columns: any = {};    
  constructor(
    private merchantService: MerchantService,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadDatatable();
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }

  loadDatatable(){
    this.columns = [
      {
        key: 'id',
        title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> SN.</div>',
        width: 60,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.idTpl,
      },
      {
        key: 'merchant_name',
        title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Merchant</div>',
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
      },
      {
        key: 'account_number',
        title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Account No.</div>',
        width: 100,
        sorting: true
      }
    ];
  }

  loadAllMerchants(){
    this.merchantService.getAllMerchants().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.allMerchantList = res.result;
        this.dataBK = this.allMerchantList;
      }
    })
  }

  onMerchantNameSearch(value: any)
  {
    this.data = this.dataBK.filter(row => row.merchant_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  }

  onAccountNumberSearch(value: any)
  {
    this.data = this.dataBK.filter(row => row.account_number.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="merchant_Name">Merchant Name:</label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)" id="merchant_Name" placeholder="Merchant Name"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="account_number">Account No.</label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)" id="account_number" placeholder="Account Number"/>
  </div>
</div>

  <ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="allMerchantList" [columns]="columns" [options]="options">
    <ngx-caption>
      </div>
    </ngx-caption>

    <ng-template #addressTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #idTpl let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">
      {{rowIndex+1}}
    </ng-template>

  </ngx-datatable>
```

> console.log(res);

gives:

```
"result":[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "merchant_name": "Appiah",
        "account_number": "332222",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-24T12:51:08.19",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "merchant_name": "Kwesi",
        "account_number": "554444",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-25T16:43:41.873",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "merchant_name": "fggffgfgfg",
        "account_number": "455654",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-25T16:46:20.77",
    }
]
```

and

> console.log(this.allMerchantList);

gives:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "merchant_name": "Appiah",
        "account_number": "332222",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-24T12:51:08.19",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "merchant_name": "Kwesi",
        "account_number": "554444",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-25T16:43:41.873",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "merchant_name": "fggffgfgfg",
        "account_number": "455654",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-25T16:46:20.77",
    }
]
```

As I enter values on the input fields in the Advance Search, I expect the result in the @tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable.

But before I even do that at all, I got this error in the component:

> error TS2339: Property 'merchant_name' does not exist on type 'never'.

> 192     this.data = this.dataBK.filter(row => row.merchant_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `<ngx-caption></div></ngx-caption>` ? Won't this create another problem?

Comment: What version of package @swimlane/ngx-datatable are you using?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrdq9z?file=src/app/app.component.ts There is it working when I directly set the dataBK. Can you maybe try to make a console.log for the this.dataBK? Maybe it contains NULL values or something?

Comment: @KevinGlier - from my post kindly look at console.log(res); and console.log(this.allMerchantList).  tHANKS

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Try `this.allMerchantList = res.result ?? [];` and if that helps, also do some logging within that subscription callback.

Comment: @KevinGlier - If you are to do service for https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrdq9z?file=src/app/app.component.ts   how will it look like. I think that should solve the problem.  Also will dataBk be in OnInit?

Comment: I changed my example now and added your Service there, but it doesn't use the HttpClient, but returns an Observable with the list of example entries. I think, if you response body doesn't contains a "result"-property, then you shouldn't use it, because http.get directly returns the response body (except when you use options.observe).

Comment: I also updated my answer. Maybe we can continue there, if there are problems left. Please also consider checking the "accept"-tick if this was the solution. :)

Comment: @KevinGlier - Thanks for all your effort, I think we are getting there. But two new issues occur as I follw the update. 1. in the component I got this error in onMerchantNameSearch and this.data highlighted  --  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)      Secondly.  In the HTML: Object is possibly 'null'    then value is highlighted in  (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)"

Comment: I can't reproduce the problems, but I did some smaller changes to the code. I added the type `Merchant[]` to `data` and `dataBK`. In the onMerchantNameSearch I used `(row) => row.merchant_name?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1` (notice the question mark). Can you maybe update the question and add your tsconfig.json content? I think it is maybe too strict.

Comment: It should be `row.merchant_name?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) ?? -1 > -1`, because the question mark wouldn't check the next calls but mean the value NULL. The double question mark means "use value to right when left is NULL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe don't use the dot-notation to get an property of an anonymous object. It could be, that the compiler sees this case wrong.

```
onMerchantNameSearch(value: any)
{
    this.data = this.dataBK.filter(row => 
        row['merchant_name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
}

onAccountNumberSearch(value: any)
{
    this.data = this.dataBK.filter(row => 
        row['account_number'].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
}
```

If you don't want to run into errors like that (and it seem to be a little problem of the TypeScript convert), then you could disable "strictNullChecks" in your `angular.json` file. Then the type "never" wouldn't be existent.

Your MerchantService is probably not correct. HttpClient.get directly returns the body, except when you are adding the options parameter and set the "observe"-propery. So try changing the subscription as follows:

```
this.merchantService.getAllMerchants().subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.allMerchantList = res;
    this.dataBK = this.allMerchantList;
})
```

Also have a look into my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrdq9z?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @midowu I changed the answer, maybe you try using row['account_number'] instead of dot notation. You shouldn't use dot-notation for anonymous objects either way.

Comment: Thanks so much, component.ts issue resolve. But the component.html issue is still there:   Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531) ,    value is highlighted in  (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)".   I am using Angulaar-13

Comment: I think (not sure - untested) that you can use it the same way. The target is also an "any"-type, so "value" could maybe not exist. So you should be able to fix it with `onMerchantNameSearch($event.target?.value ?? '')`. This passes an empty string to the method if "value" is not given (what actually shouldn't be the case, but we need this the compiler to know) :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning instance to null. You should initialize the property by defining it first. On `row` your trying to access `merchant_name` but it may never be there or have anything.

Quick and easy fix could be to define what dataBK has.
`dataBK: any[] = [];`
If we don't care what it has or data type may change we can just use any.

Proper way would to create an interface. What `dataBK` holds? An array of Rows. Okay - what kind of Rows? We include `merchant_name, account_number...` in row objects. Then we always know, that `dataBK` will hold an array or `Row` objects. And we have defined, that `Row` object will have such properties to be accessed. Leaving in the `?` as I can't be 100% sure they will be there to be accessed, maybe you do - in case you can remove the questions marks.

```js
dataBK: Row[] = [];

interface Row {
id?: number;
merchant_name?: string;
account_number?: string;
merchant_status?: number;
created_date?: string;
}
```

Comment: As I did dataBK: Row[] = [],   I got this error: Type 'Row[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Also when I move away from interface and use dataBK: any[] = [].   I got this error  'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Comment: @midowu When is dataBK even set?

Comment: @KevinGlier - It is set OnInit

Comment: @midowu But not in your example. Check my StackBlitz link in the comment section of your question. The entries are now visible and it is also searchable. It must have something to do with your Service. Maybe you can add the code of the method to your question?

Comment: @KevinGlier - I have updated the entire code as it is at the moment. As I stated, the error now becomes:  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'